# I need to replace the values in the columns in my DataFrame with some groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

---

**Problem formulation**

Currently, `df['B']` has values ranging from 0 to 16. I would like them replaced with as follows:

```
  S where df['B'] <= 2
  M where 2 < df['B'] <= 6
  L where df['B'] >= 6
```

---

**DataFrame**

```
A       B
5180    2
5784    0
5784    16
7269    4
7268    12
```

---

**Desired output**

> ```
> A       B
> 5180    S
> 5784    S
> 5784    L
> 7269    M
> 7268    L
> ```

Is there pandas function to do that?

Comment: We need sample data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create new values in a pandas dataframe column based on values from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547168/how-to-create-new-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-based-on-values-from-anoth)

Comment: And we need at least 1 question

Comment: @Shiven Singh its a basic binning operation, linked answer above will help

Answer (score 0):

I assume your dataframe's name is `df`.

```
df['B'] = pd.cut(df['B'], bins = [0, 3, 7, 17], labels=["S", "M", "L"])
```

Cutting into bins means, that:

> ```
> for range [0,3) we use label[0] ('S')  
>
> for range [3,7) we use label[1] ('M')
>
> for range [7,17) we use label[2] ('L')
> ```